# Using \DefineBibliographyStrings (getting undefined)?

Tags: biblatex

If I try to compile this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  teststring      = {Test string},
}
\begin{document}
\parbox{2pt}{\hspace*{1pt}Testing my statement}
\end{document}
```

... it fails with:

```
! Package keyval Error: teststring undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.6 \begin{document}
```

Why? I'd think that `\DefineBibliographyStrings` would, well, define `teststring`? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\DefineBibliographyStrings` stores definitions for *known* strings for a language. If you want to declare a completly new string you must declare it first:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\NewBibliographyString{teststring}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  teststring      = {Test string},
}
\begin{document}
\parbox{2pt}{\hspace*{1pt}Testing my statement}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for that, @UlrikeFischer - I can't believe I forgot to check `texdoc biblatex` for that `:)` Cheers!