# Overload Biblatex thesis style and define

Tags: biblatex

In one of my report, I need to differentiate several "type" of thesis, which are 
basically Law PhD thesis and a special one, called "Thèse d'habilitation", which is a pre-requisite to become "full" Law Professor in some Swiss Universities. This is a follow-up [from my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427231/formatting-issue-with-declarebibliographydriver-in-my-custom-biblatex-style-base)

The entry should only differ by the bibliography entry, meaning that the type should be :

- Plain thesis : "Author first, Title, Thèse City Year"
- These d'habilitatiom should be : "Author first, Title, Thèse d'habilitation City Year"

### My analysis

So I've bumped on the type redefinition of biblatex documentation, page 13 (2.1.2 Type Aliases) and my problem is basically to create new Type alias and link the "type" field to the right entry. That's what "biblatex" does with the "alias type" phdthesis and master thesis, which is :
 - Link to the thesis entry type
 - Define the field "type" with a default string

But I'm stuck with what I've identified as being the code used in biblatex.cfg file :

```
% ------------------------------------------------------------------
% Driver sourcemaps
% ------------------------------------------------------------------
\DeclareDriverSourcemap[datatype=bibtex]{
  \map{
    \step[fieldset=day, null]
  }
  \map{
    \step[typesource=conference, typetarget=inproceedings]
    \step[typesource=electronic, typetarget=online]
    \step[typesource=www,        typetarget=online]
  }
  \map{
    \step[typesource=mastersthesis, typetarget=thesis, final]
    \step[fieldset=type,            fieldvalue=mathesis]
  }
  \map{
    \step[typesource=phdthesis, typetarget=thesis, final]
    \step[fieldset=type,        fieldvalue=phdthesis]
  }
  \map{
    \step[typesource=techreport, typetarget=report, final]
    \step[fieldset=type,         fieldvalue=techreport]
  }
  \map{
    \step[fieldsource=hyphenation,   fieldtarget=langid]
    \step[fieldsource=address,       fieldtarget=location]
    \step[fieldsource=school,        fieldtarget=institution]
    \step[fieldsource=annote,        fieldtarget=annotation]
    \step[fieldsource=archiveprefix, fieldtarget=eprinttype]
    \step[fieldsource=journal,       fieldtarget=journaltitle]
    \step[fieldsource=primaryclass,  fieldtarget=eprintclass]
    \step[fieldsource=key,           fieldtarget=sortkey]
    \step[fieldsource=pdf,           fieldtarget=file]
  }
}
```

First, I've tried to declare some new field in my custom lbx file, as showed in [the other question I had](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427231/formatting-issue-with-declarebibliographydriver-in-my-custom-biblatex-style-base). This gave me :

**biblatex-xawi.lbx**

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{typethesis = {Thèse}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{typethabilitation = {Thèse d'habilitation}}
```

And I've added a copy-paste of the biblatex source :

**biblatex-xawi.bbx**

```
\DeclareDriverSourcemap[datatype=bibtex]{
      \map{
        \step[typesource=thesedroit, typetarget=thesis, final]
        \step[fieldset=type,            fieldvalue = typethesis]
      }
      \map{
        \step[typesource=thesehabilitation, typetarget=thesis, final]
        \step[fieldset=type,        typethabilitation = phdthesis]
      }
    }
```

But as before, I'm not really gifted with the Biblatex style creation, as I'm having an error :

```
Package xkeyval Error: `typethabilitation' undefined in families `blx@sourcemap@step'.

See the xkeyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.116     }

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

### My questions

**Question 1** : in general, how can I create "simple" alias, for example redirecting my entry type "ouvragegeneral" to a "book" type (in order to help by users).

**Question 2** : if I need to create alias and do some "piping" how can I create my 2 thesis types ?

### Accepted answer & feedback

The error returned was that my custom string being defined but not 
See other [question&answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242267/using-definebibliographystrings-getting-undefined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that also maps `@habilthesis` to `@thesis` with `type` `habilthesis`. It also adds the generic type `thesis` to all `@thesis` entries without an explicit `type`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@phdthesis{normalthesis,
  author = {Author Normal},
  title = {Title PhD Thesis},
  date = {2016},
}
@thesis{mormalthesis,
  author = {Author Mormal},
  title = {Title PhD Thesis},
  date = {2017},
  type = {phdthesis},
}
@thesis{mythesis,
  author = {Author These},
  title = {Title Thèse},
  date = {2014},
}
@habilthesis{habilthesis,
  author = {Author Habilitation},
  title = {Title Thése Habilitation},
  date = {2014},
}
@thesis{habilthesis2,
  author = {Author Habilitation},
  title = {Title Thése Habilitation},
  date = {2014},
  type = {habilthesis},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\NewBibliographyString{thesis,habilthesis}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{
  thesis      = {thèse},
  habilthesis = {thèse d'habilitation},
}

\DeclareStyleSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex,overwrite=false]{
    \map{
      \step[typesource=habilthesis, typetarget=thesis, final]
      \step[fieldset=type,          fieldvalue=habilthesis]
    }
    \map{
      \pertype{thesis}
      \step[fieldset=type, fieldvalue=thesis]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Let me add a few more words since we discussed this in the comments to the other answer.

- It would be possible and maybe even conceptually nicer to only use the `@thesis` entry type and give the thesis type in the `type` field.
- I do not see the value of creating French entry types like `@these` for `@thesis` or German localisations like `@buch` for `@book`. This will *severely* impact portability of a `.bib` file that uses these types and makes it essentially incompatible with any other style. Since people need to learn the valid types anyway, I think it is acceptable to let them learn the English types.
- Ideally there is no distinction between '`biblatex` commands' and 'Biber commands'. As far as I am concerned, there are only `biblatex` commands and a subset of these is not supported by BibTeX or BibTeX8. BibTeX is considered a legacy backend now and even the `biblatex` documentation generally assumes that new documents always use Biber. Some commands trigger effects on the Biber-level, some trigger effects on the `biblatex`-level, others work on all levels.
  It is not at all considered impure to 'mix' these commands and there is no reason why it should be discouraged to do so. 
  Of course it can greatly help to understand the workings of your style if you know which command changes what at what level, but you should not avoid the Biber-level just for the sake of avoiding it. Some things that can be done easily on the Biber-level can be recreated with more work and a few rough edges on the `biblatex` level - but in general there is little point in doing that.
- The command `\DeclareStyleSourcemap` is documented in the `biblatex` manual.

Comment: (+1) Glad to see you incorporated the point on portability of the bib file. :)  I do think this is a relevant issue. And the OP may well get to define a new entrytype that's `bibtex`-driver compatible with the use of a datamodel. But I really don't see what'd be the point of that.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are overcomplicating this one. The `thesis` entrytype should handle your requirements with little overhead, if any.

The `type` field of `thesis` works the following way. If there is as bibstring defined that equals the `type`, then it uses the bibstring, otherwise it uses the field as is.

So, there is one very simple alternative, which is to write "Thèse" or "Thèse d'habilitation" directly in the `type` field:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @thesis{normalthesis,
    author = {Author Normal},
    title = {Title Normal Thesis},
    date = {2016},
    type = {phdthesis},
  }
  @thesis{mythesis,
    author = {Author These},
    title = {Title Thèse},
    date = {2014},
    type = {Thèse},
  }
  @thesis{habilthesis,
    author = {Author Habilitation},
    title = {Title Thése Habilitation},
    date = {2014},
    type = {Thèse d'habilitation},
  }

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

If you want something more automatic and eventually localized, you have simply to create the bibstring and define it to the relevant language:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @thesis{normalthesis,
    author = {Author Normal},
    title = {Title Normal Thesis},
    date = {2016},
    type = {phdthesis},
  }
  @thesis{mythesis,
    author = {Author These},
    title = {Title Thèse},
    date = {2014},
    type = {mythesis},
  }
  @thesis{habilthesis,
    author = {Author Habilitation},
    title = {Title Thése Habilitation},
    date = {2014},
    type = {habilthesis},
  }

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\NewBibliographyString{mythesis,habilthesis}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{
  mythesis = {Thèse},
  habilthesis = {Thèse d'habilitation},
}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Either way, the result is:

[image]

Comment: +1) I'd prefer `thesis` instead of `mythesis`, a sourcemap could be used to make sure that a `@thesis` without a specific `type` field always gets `type = {thesis}` and you could of course recreate what Biber does for `@phdthesis` for `@habilthesis` as well: https://gist.github.com/moewew/5217d7a0aa8622db971739ad758d4145

Comment: @moewe, with `mythesis` I was trying to illustrate the mechanism on how an arbitrary bibstring, as long as it is defined, is sufficient. And yes, we could have the entrytype with the sourcemap, and this was requested by the OP. But I feel it is unnecessary and would not help the portability of the bib file, thus my recommendation to use plain `@thesis`.

Comment: @moewe, furthermore, I think a `thesis` `type` for the `thesis` `entrytype` may well qualify as a "tongue twister".  :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I guess what I missed was mainly the \NewBibliographyString command. @moewe your code is more complete, as it explains the DeclareStyleSourcemap command. As I understand, this is Biber command ?

Comment: @XaWi Indeed, `\DeclareStyleSourcemap` can only be used with Biber and makes Biber pre-process your `.bib` file as desired.

Comment: So there isn't any mechanism to provide this mapping and field assignment on a biblatex-level ?

Comment: @XaWi Why would you want that? It might be possible to mimic some of the effects of the shown `\DeclareStyleSourcemap` on the `biblatex` level. That would definitely mean more work, it would be less elegant and it might not behave as expected in all cases. Nowadays everyone should be using Biber as backend anyway (BibTeX is considered a legacy backend, even the `biblatex` documentation assumes you use Biber). So there is no point to restrict yourself to `biblatex`-level commands when Biber can do it for you much quicker.

Comment: @XaWi What I will say, though, is that you can get away without any mappings of entry types if you only ever use the entrytype `@thesis` and populate its `type` field yourself with the appropriate strings (`thesis`, `phdthesis`, `habilthesis`) - this is essentially what the answer here does.

Comment: Well, your solution with the mapping is ideal, because (1) it allows to create french/german name for my users (i.e. use an @these type) and to abstract away the complication ; (2) it prevent a copy-paste error with the "type", which will be constant and imposed strings. So all in all, the answer is good, and my case may be overthought, but this is for a "better good"

Comment: And, as per biblatex/biber part, I mainly wanted to understand the moving parts here. It was just puzzling to mix biber & biblatex commands, as I could not find the DeclareStyleSourcemap command anywhere. But in all, the bbx file "drives" the biblatex and the biber backend, so this all makes sense after some thoughts, thanks !

Comment: @moewe, given the discussion here, please do feel free to add your original comment and code as another answer.